# Javadoc: using @link to link to a description of an interface

Tags: hyperlink, javadoc

I am a technical writer who is editing the Javadoc comments written by our developers.  One of the comments was like

```
/**
 * Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 
 * {@link SomeInterface}
 */
```

When submitted to Jenkins, the build failed with an error like "Unresolved link/see tag" so I made the following change:

```
/**
 * Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 
 * {@link com.example.foo.SomeInterface}
 */
```

I thought that would have fixed the problem (changing to a fully-qualified interface name), but it is still failing with the same error message.

In reading http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#link the first sentence says

```
Inserts an in-line link with visible text label that points to the documentation
for the specified package, class or member name of a referenced class.
```

which specifically says "referenced class" and does not include "interface".  How can I @link to the description for a public interface?

Comment: I don't think "class" in those instructions exclude interfaces. Try linking to another class in that same package, does it work? How about a class in another sub package (like com.example.other.ClassName).

Comment: Yes, there is already a second @link to a different class in the same package and it does not generate an error message.

Comment: Well, I hate to ask this, but does the interface actually exist in that same diresctory, the one that that JavaDoc is looking in? Try linking to another *interface* in the same package.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  We've determined the cause and it is specific to our setup for the project.